# Is the same stan file can be used in Rstan and cmdtanr?

Tags: stan, rstan

I'm now using Rstan to use stan. But, it seems that cmdstanr is becoming popular. I'm wondering if the stan file used with Rstan can be also used in cmdstanr? I'm estimating a simple linear multilevel model.

Comment: Yes, .stan files are independent of the stan implementation. you just need to make sure that the version of stan you're using in rstan or cmdstanr fits the version of stan syntax you're using.